# converting from list to integer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to get an integer out of a listitem.
i first collected the items to put in the dropdownlist and then i try to take the integer out of the items

It worked before(got a nice string with interests in database), but more often than not, i get an error for trying to make an integer out of a listitem
[image]

I would like to solve this so it works 100% of the time so it doesn't look like an incomplete project when i present this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.InteresseLijst1, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Interesse1, Model.InteresseLijst1)            
    </div>
</div>
```

these are the used properties from my viewmodel

```
[Display(Name = "Interesse 1")]        
public SelectList InteresseLijst1 { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Interesse 2")]        
public SelectList InteresseLijst2 { get; set; }
public int Interesse1 { get; set; }
public int Interesse2 { get; set; }

public string Interesses { get; set; }
```

this is my Get-action to register where i make my selectlists

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterViewModel rvm = new RegisterViewModel();
    List<Categorie> categorielijst = CategoryRepository.GetCategories();
    rvm.InteresseLijst1 = new SelectList(categorielijst, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
    rvm.InteresseLijst2 = new SelectList(categorielijst, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
    return View(rvm);
}
```

and this is my post where i use the integers collected from the selectlist.
I convert to json to keep it in my database for further comparison on other parts of the site.

```
#region verschillend

if(model.Interesse1 != model.Interesse2)
{
    int[] interesses = new int[2] { model.Interesse1, model.Interesse2 };
    string sInteresses = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interesses);
    model.Interesses = sInteresses;

    //other code                          

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    AddErrors(result);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? Do you get any error?

Comment: added a picture of the error

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. And based on that code, an exception should *not* be being thrown on the highlighted line. It's possible that you just need to clean and rebuild your project. Most likely, the Razor view is referencing out-dated code.

Comment: I just tried cleaning and rebuilding project and going over it again, the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of a workaround, i managed to get rid of the error. I changed the way the items are displayed by adding properties to items in a list. Then i collect the values of the properties in my controller with Request.Form["propertyname"] and it worked